# Why can't I import config?

Tags: python

I have a config.yml file with api keys in it, further, I have a .py file which greps for it.

I should theoretically be able to import config, and I can do so when I move the config.py file from the main directory into the correct subdirectory, but that doesn't quite work efficiently.

Forgive the poor attempt at file structure formatting.

in `directory`

- servers

  - backend

    - file1.py
    - file2.py
    - file_i_need_config.py
- config.py

I am trying:

```
from config import Config

print(Config.get_property("api_key_for_thing").unwrap())
```

and receiving the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you running your code? What command do you use? And what directory are you running the command from?

Comment: To import `config`, you need `directory` to be on your Python search path. That's only going to be added implicitly if you are executing a script that's directly in `directory`, not one of its subdirectories. `file_i_need_config.py` will only be able to import `file1` and `file2` without adding other directories to the search path explicitly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just figured it out. I was trying to run file_i_need_config.py from inside the directory itself, running python -m servers.backend.file_i_need_config worked, thank you!

Comment: @chepner thank you, this helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

With the kind souls above, I figured it out.

I was executing within the directory of `user:backend % python -m file_i_need_config` from there.

Needed to execute from the parent directory via `user:directory % python -m servers.backend.file_i_need_config`

Answer (score 0):

That's because the python will by default import a file from his currenty path.

**First import the lib sys**

```
import sys
```

Insert the path of the folder you want

```
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/foo/myfolder_that_has_configfile')
```

import the file normally

```
from config import config
```